# How to receive incoming data in buffer form from the Node.js net module?

Tags: node.js

When I receive incoming data from net server, it's always a string form.

It cause that some byte data was lost.

But according to [Node.js docs page](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v6.x/api/net.html), it seems that the data can be received in buffer format.

> **Event: 'data'**
> Added in: v0.1.90
> Emitted when data is received. The argument data will be a Buffer or String. Encoding of data is set by socket.setEncoding(). (See the Readable Stream section for more information.)

Note that the data will be lost if there is no listener when a Socket emits a 'data' event.

How can I receive the data in a buffer form?

```
let net_server = require('net');

let server = net_server.createServer(function(client) {

    client.setTimeout(10000);
    client.setEncoding('utf8');

    client.on('data', function(recvBuffer) {
        // recvBuffer is string form
    });
});

server.listen(process.argv[2], function() {
});
```

Comment: Link and image has disappeared. 
Here is link of document page -> [link](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v6.x/api/net.html#net_event_data)

Comment: Try to remove `client.setEncoding('utf8');` i think thist line is telling node that the data is string with utf8 encoding so it automatically turns buffer into string for you.

Comment: └ Thank you very much! It's work.

Comment: Encoding in any form changes the buffer to string form.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The problem was caused by this line.

```
client.setEncoding('utf8'); // Delete this line
```

Encoding in any form changes the buffer to string form.